# how to add table to sqlite3 database

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

How can I add a database to my SQLite3 database?
I always get this error.

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Timespans#index

Showing C:/xampp/htdocs/fluxcapacitor/app/views/timespans/index.html.erb where line #19 raised:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: timespans: SELECT "timespans".* FROM "timespans"
```

I tried adding my table to my`schema.rb`, but it doesn't work. It is always overwritten, when I run

`rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=development`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should generate [migration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html):

```
bundle exec rails g migration create_timespans
```

And in the migration, you should have:

```
class CreateTimespans < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :timespans
      t.string :column1
      t.string :column2
      # ...
    end
  end
end
```

And run it with `bundle exec rake db:migrate`.

This is the proper way to make changes in your DB schema in Rails application.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use migrations to make changes to your database. See [the Active Record Migrations
 guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html) for the details.

Generally speaking, the process is something like:

1. `rails generate migration create_timespans` generates an empty migration for you.
2. Edit the created migration to setup the table like you want it to. This should be pretty similar to what you've already added in `schema.rb`.
3. `rake db:migrate` then applies those changes to the database.